# How to return list of django model instances as JSON?

Tags: python, json, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a view:

```
class ListUnseenFriendRequests(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        friendship_requests_list = Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user)
        friendship_requests_rough_json = [serializers.serialize('json', [obj]) for obj in friendship_requests_list]
        friendship_requests_json = [obj.strip("[]") for obj in friendship_requests_rough_json]
        return Response(friendship_requests_json, content_type="application/json")
```

This gives me the following in JSON:

```
[
    "{\"model\": \"friendship.friendshiprequest\", \"pk\": 8, \"fields\": {\"from_user\": 6, \"to_user\": 4, \"message\": \"\", \"created\": \"2017-07-27T14:02:28.492Z\", \"rejected\": null, \"viewed\": null}}",
    "{\"model\": \"friendship.friendshiprequest\", \"pk\": 13, \"fields\": {\"from_user\": 2, \"to_user\": 4, \"message\": \"\", \"created\": \"2017-07-27T16:47:24.863Z\", \"rejected\": null, \"viewed\": null}}",
    "{\"model\": \"friendship.friendshiprequest\", \"pk\": 20, \"fields\": {\"from_user\": 14, \"to_user\": 4, \"message\": \"\", \"created\": \"2017-07-31T08:03:27.887Z\", \"rejected\": null, \"viewed\": null}}",
    "{\"model\": \"friendship.friendshiprequest\", \"pk\": 22, \"fields\": {\"from_user\": 22, \"to_user\": 4, \"message\": \"\", \"created\": \"2017-08-01T11:52:08.830Z\", \"rejected\": null, \"viewed\": null}}"
]
```

On the android client side when making a request to this view the following error occurs:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

I think this means there shouldn't be any `"` wrapping the JSON response. If this is the problem how do I remove them? If this is not the problem how do I fix this?

Comment: You can use `JSONResponse` instead. Use this `from django.http import JsonResponse` and then `return JSONResponse(friendship_requests_json)`

Comment: Exact same error occurs. Makes no difference in the response format.

Comment: I validated the json that you have put in your question and it seem legit. What's the issue?

Comment: This is the error I get when my client tries to process the response: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]`

Comment: Basically I think it means the only thing that isn't right with the response is the " at the start and end of every line in my question.

Comment: @check out my answer. I have edited it.

Comment: Now the response is the following: [
    {
        "pk": 29,
        "model": "friendship.friendshiprequest",
        "fields": {
            "created": "2017-08-02T09:06:54.272Z",
            "rejected": null,
            "to_user": 20,
            "from_user": 5,
            "message": "",
            "viewed": null
        }
    }
]

Comment: Is there a way to keep the pk json attribute but not the model attribute. And is there a way to not display the fields in a fields list?

Comment: Yes! Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: So where should I apply the values() function, since the friendship_requests_list is a list not a queryset?

Comment: Like this `Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user).values('pk','some_other_field')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to create a serializer for your Friend model and using that serializer class to convert it to JSON. 
But if you don't want to use that this will give you the near solution to what you are trying

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
class ListUnseenFriendRequests(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        friendship_requests_list = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user))
        return JSONResponse(friendship_requests_list,safe=False)
```

`serializers.serialize` method is serializing the Django objects and convert them into a representational string. As we know that the string should be a JSON representation we converted the string to JSON sent it as `JSONResponse`. 
Refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#serializing-non-dictionary-objects)

Comment: What about using a ListAPIView?

Comment: @TomFinet There are many ways to do this. I just suggested the one which you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to use ListAPIView ideally

Comment: The response is the same as what I start with except it has quotation marks around the outside of the  starting square bracket [ .

Comment: @TomFinet Have you created serializer class for Friend ?

Comment: The `Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user)` returns a FriendshipRequest list. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py#L71) , it's a library, so it's not me that wrote it.

Comment: try this `JSONResponse(serializers.serialize('json',list(friendship_requests_list)),safe=False)`

Comment: Returns the exact same response.

Comment: `"[{\"model\": \"friendship.friendshiprequest\", \"pk\": 29, \"fields\": {\"from_user\": 5, \"to_user\": 20, \"message\": \"\", \"created\": \"2017-08-02T09:06:54.272Z\", \"rejected\": null, \"viewed\": null}}]"`

Comment: @TomFinet do you mind if you send data like `{ "friend_requests" : [ your_list_inside ]}` If so then you can try this `JSONResponse(serializers.serialize('json',{"friend_requests":list(friendship_re‌​quests_list)}),safe=F‌​alse)`

Comment: Yeh I can't do that. All I need is a way to remove the `"` in front of the `{`

Comment: @TomFinet Check this out i have tested it and it is working correctly